# Running python program with admin priviledges without the UAC prompt

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, uac

I am making a python app and compiled it using pyinstaller. There is no problem when the user installs the app only for himself/herself , but when he/she installs for all users, it gives a permission denied error.

It's basically a chatbot I made for a project. When the program is run the first time, it takes some basic data from the user and stores in a file. There's no problem when the program is installed for that user only,i.e., the program in stored in the user's appdata folder.

But when the user tries to install it for all users, i.e., the program is stored in the program files(x86) folder, it gives a permission error as the folder is system protected.

I tried to bypass it by adding the --uac-admin flag, but it is not convenient to go through the UAC prompt every time the user wants to run the program.

I wanted to know if there was a way to run the program as admin without the UAC prompt.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot do that. If the UAC prompt appears, you can't "bypass" (or auto-accept, the "yes" button) the UAC prompt. (Imagine if this were possible: It's is exactly what all malware would do.)

Comment: But is there a legitimate way to do so. Because commercial applications like microsoft teams do not ask for uac rights even when they are stored in the program files (x86) folder, which requires admin priviledges..

Comment: The fact that an administrator-level process _installed_ a program to a protected location does not mean that the program requires administrator privilege when _running_ that program.

Comment: But in my case, it is giving me a permission denied error. I am unable to write data to a file. Any Legitimate way to do so

Comment: You are going to need to update your question with the precise specifics of what you are trying to do. As written your question provides insufficient information.

Comment: ok, have updated the question.

Comment: Regardless of where your program gets installed, it should only write user data to a path that users have access to.

Comment: Can you suggest me some directories where i can store the data without requiring admin priviledges in windows

Comment: You should be able to use a directory in the user's profile. (This question is really too broad for stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you want all users to be able to modify your application in it's **Program Files (x86)** folder
- so have your installation program change the permissions on your folder
- so that <kbd>Everyone</kbd> has **Full Control** to the folder

If you've decided that anyone should be able to modify your chat program at any time without having to be an administrator: then give them permission.

Here's some pseudocode that will grant Full Control to all users.

```
procedure GrantAllUsersFullControlOfFileOrFolder(Path: string);
const
    SECURITY_NULL_SID_AUTHORITY:    TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,0));  //S-1-0  ntifs.h
    SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY:   TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,1));  //S-1-1
    SECURITY_LOCAL_SID_AUTHORITY:   TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,2));  //S-1-2
    SECURITY_CREATOR_SID_AUTHORITY: TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,3));  //S-1-3
    SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY:          TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,5));  //S-1-5

    //Relative identifiers (RIDs)
    SECURITY_NULL_RID  = 0;         //in authority S-1-0
    SECURITY_WORLD_RID = 0;         //in authority S-1-1
    SECURITY_LOCAL_RID = 0;         //in authority S-1-2
    SECURITY_CREATOR_OWNER_RID = 0; //in authority S-1-3
    SECURITY_CREATOR_GROUP_RID = 1; //in authority S-1-3

    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID = $00000020; // 32 --> S-1-5-32
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS     = $00000220; //544 --> S-1-5-32-544
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_USERS      = $00000221; //545 --> S-1-5-32-545 A local group that represents all users in the domain.
var
    usersSID: PSID;
//  res: BOOL;
    sd: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
    oldAcl, newAcl: PACL;
    dw: DWORD;
    ea: EXPLICIT_ACCESS;
begin
    //Create a well-known SID for the "Users" group (S-1-5-32-545)
    usersSid := StringToSid('S-1-5-32-545'); //well-known "Users" group
    try
        //Get the current DACL. Free SecurityDescriptor with LocalFree
        sd := nil;
        dw := GetNamedSecurityInfo(PChar(Path), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, @oldAcl, nil, {var}sd);
        if (dw <> ERROR_SUCCESS) then
            RaiseLastWin32Error;
        try
            // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new ACE
            ZeroMemory(@ea, SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
            ea.grfAccessPermissions  := GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_EXECUTE {or GENERIC_ALL}; //Yes, it's not "really" full control
            ea.grfAccessMode         := GRANT_ACCESS;
            ea.grfInheritance        := SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
            ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm   := TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
            ea.Trustee.TrusteeType   := TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP; //TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
            ea.Trustee.ptstrName     := PChar(usersSID);

            // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE into the existing ACL. Use LocalFree to free newAcl
            dw := SetEntriesInAcl(1, @ea, oldAcl, {var}newAcl); //use LocalFree to free newAcl
            if dw <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
                RaiseLastOSError(dw);
            try
                //Attach the new ACL as the object's new DACL
                dw := SetNamedSecurityInfo(PChar(Path), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, newAcl, nil);
                if (dw <> ERROR_SUCCESS) then
                    RaiseLastWin32Error;
            finally
                LocalFree(HLOCAL(newAcl));
            end;
        finally
            LocalFree(HLOCAL(sd));
        end;
    finally
        LocalFree(HLOCAL(usersSid));
    end;
end;
```

It also means that malware can modify your program at any time. But you're OK with that, as you said you want any standard users to be able to modify it your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will surely give it a try.

BTW, for the time being, I've disabled the universal installation for the app as that was causing the issue.